# evolution of C and gamma in SVR with the size of training examples

Tags: svm, hyperparameter

Do you know how C and gamma evolve while the size of training examples (X) rises ?
I have found C and gamma for 10% and 20% of my data and I would like to save time. Can I determine C and gamma for my whole data with the two C and gamma I already have ?